# CSS media queries break at 5 specific resolution sizes....what?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have just finished my first javascript project (a 3D website using three.js) but right before publishing I realized that I had not optimized the dimensions and contents to look the same when accessing the site other than a 1920x1080 browser. So I started looking at how to do that and discovered how to set DevicePixelRatio or use media queries with CSS. After googling and looking through stackoverflow I settled on using CSS media queries but I am running into 2 weird problems.

1)
I am changing the size of my font depending on the resolution but as I am using Developer Tools to dynamically change the viewport(?) size in the browser. I click on "Toggle Device Toolbar" then select responsive and start scaling down to see my font size changes take effect.

They have been working as expected except for this, even though there are no gaps in resolution size for when to apply media queries, there are two points, specific dimensions of resolution or viewport (whatever F12 lets you change, i don't know what it's called), are excluded. For example...

I have media queries to take effect when the device width resolution is

between 600 to 699px
apply font size change
apply scaling of small image
between 700 to 739px
apply font size change
apply scaling of small image
between 740 to 767px
apply font size change
apply scaling of small image

on and on and on...

here is the code...

```
@media (min-width: 650px) and (max-width: 699px) {
  * {
    font-size:35%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 2.2em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 1.2em;
  }
  #join, #poo, #dex {
    font-size: 800%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) and (max-width: 739px) {
  * {
    font-size: 45%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 1.8em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 1.3em;
  }
  #join, #poo, #dex {
    font-size: 600%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 740px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  * {
    font-size: 50%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 2.7em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 1.4em;
  }
  #join, #poo, #dex {
    font-size: 500%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 833px) {
  * {
    font-size: 65%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 1.5em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 1.8em;
  }
  #join, #poo, #dex {
    font-size: 400%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 834px) and (max-width: 899px) {
  * {
    font-size: 75%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 2.1em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 0.8em;
  }
  #join, #poo, #dex {
    font-size: 300%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
  * {
    font-size: 80%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 1.9em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 0.8em;
  }
  #join, #poo, #dex {
    font-size: 300%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1098px)  {
  * {
    font-size: 90%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 1.8em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 0.9em;
  }
  #join, #poo, #dex {
    font-size: 250%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1099px) and (max-width: 1199px)  {
  * {
    font-size: 95%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 1.7em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 1em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  * {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 1.5em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 0.8em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1281px) and (max-width: 1339px) {
  * {
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 1.6em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 0.8em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1340px) and (max-width: 1399px)  {
  * {
    font-size: 115%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 1.3em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 1.1em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) and (max-width: 1649px)  {
  * {
    font-size: 125%;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 1.1em;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 1650px) and (max-width: 1919px)  {
  * {
    font-size: 140%;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 1.3em;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2879px) {
  * {
    font-size: 150%;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 1.5em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 2880px) and (max-width: 3839px) {
  * {
    font-size: 180%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 2.2em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 1.7em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 3840px) {
  * {
    font-size: 220%;
  }
  #icon {
    width: 2.4em;
  }
  #tg {
    width: 1.9em;
  }
  #comm {
    font-size: 300%;
  }  
}
```

I chose those dimensions because I googled "list of display resolution of mobile devices" so that I can ensure that when I test my site viewed by those dimensions that it will still display as intended.

Like I said, the font size changes work smoothly as I size down the "viewable box in F12".... but if I put it on resolution width 767px exactly, it is as if the media query doesn't exist and my text goes to 100% which is of course way too big for the small display size.

I clicked on "More Options" in the "Device Toolbar" and selected "show media queries" which brings up some colored bars on the top of the toolbar showing where the media queries exists as you resize the display area. I can see at the top that there are two gaps where a media query is not existing and that is at 699px, 767px, 833px, 899px, and at 1023px. Even though those numbers are explicitly covered in my media queries (in the "max-width:" part), the media queries are not applying to those. I thought it was the syntax at first but other numbers that I included as the max-width: dimension don't revert back to 100% so I can't decipher anything consistent for me to understand what the issue is.

It looks in Mathematics when we use parenthesis instead of brackets to denote that we are not including a number in a solution set. Ya know, how [0,35) means from and including 0 to but not including 35. Except I don't think that is how CSS uses brackets and parenthesis. and I don't have any other media queries anywhere.

I tried using "!important" where I specified what size to change the font to, and then as I was writing this post I tried changing the number in the media query from 767px to 767.9999999px and that worked.... *major eye roll*

So are the numbers 699, 767, 833, 899, and 1023 just forbidden by CSS *sarcasm from frustration* or what? I don't understand.

Wait...... it's not something dumb like you can't use odd numbers in media queries or something like that, right? because it didn't say that anywhere that I could see and I googled different websites and referred to 3 different youtube videos on media queries.

problem 2)
There are 4 total sections where text is shown on the screen. Most of the text consists of
an image of a logo as a "bullet point" on each of 3 lines of text. As I go through the media queries and apply the font size change, the bullet point image also scales... but at a much faster rate so I had to INCREASE the size of the image to have it shrink SLOWER to be able to still be the same proportional size to the text as I check each of the media query sizes. So I went through each media query and compensated for the image correctly....but now, one of the lines of text (a

with an id; so I know I didn't also accidentally refer to it somewhere else) shrinks EVEN FASTER than the image.... Idk what the heck is going on. I made sure to use 16px as the font size in the HTML section in my CSS page and I used "em" units everywhere else.  I am lost. I'll post the rest of my CSS code here.

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}


.slide1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: 55%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
}

.slide1 h2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:7%;
  left: 18%;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
.slide1 #p1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  left: 18%;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: bold; 
}
.slide1 #p2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 18%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* text-align: left; */  
}
.slide1 #p3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 18%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.slide2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  /* transform: translate(0, -50%); */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
.slide2 h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12%;
  left: 27.5%;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#contract {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left:13%;
  font-size: 2.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
#clip {
  width:1em;
}
#icon {
  width:1.3em;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#erc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48%;
  left:13%;
  font-size: 2.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#buy {
  position: absolute;
  top: 66%;
  left:13%;
  font-size: 2.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#contracts {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  top:auto;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slide3 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 0%);
}
.slide3 h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18.5%;
  left: 42%;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
}
#info {
  position:absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left:31%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#poo {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:21%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#dex {
  position:absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left:21%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slide4 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top: 35%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}

.slide4 h4 {
  position:absolute;
  top:30%;
  left:38%;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
#comm {
  position: absolute;
  top: 52%;
  left: 28%;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#join {
  position: absolute;
  top:70%;
  left: 30%;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#tg {
  width:1.1em;
}
```

I have no styling in my HTML code so there shouldn't be any conflicting font size or image size from HTML.

Can someone help me make sense of this please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#mq-min-max) says that viewport width can potentially be calculated as a fractional value due to zooming, hidpi, etc. since your media queries specify bounded ranges, and there are holes in between those ranges, it's possible for certain viewports to not match any media queries at all.

since you're using the same set of selectors and rules inside of each media query, you don't need `max-width` at all; just use `min-width` and let the CSS engine do the rest.

Comment: thank you, that seemed to get rid of those gaps. One quick related question, if i have a <p> tag and inside of it I have text and an image in the same line, then when I create a media query changing the "font-size", does that then include the img inside the p tag also? Because my img is scaling differently and I can't tell why.

Comment: I would recommend opening a new SO question to discuss that.  it is a different question with a different answer, and a separate question will help future users with similar problems discover the answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You should post a link to the site. A picture is worth 1,000 words. Otherwise I fail to see how CSS breakpoints are a discussion for resizing the renderer.

Always declare the rem on the html/body element, and then use ems/rems primarily as a constant variable. Scale relationships can appear counterintuitive if you use the wrong unit combination.

As far as media queries go, breakpoints will drive you crazy: resolution, actual pixels, orientation, dpi, user-scale, operating system, browser, ui chrome, device type. [You should use a snippet, or a library that rebrands a snippet](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile).

Comment: I haven't uploaded the website because I hadn't gotten past this part but I'll get a link when it's uploaded. As far as the units, yea that confirms what I was thinking, that I can set the root size of the font/image then use media queries with em units so they are all proportional. 

I agree with you that "I fail to see how CSS breakpoints are a discussion for resizing the renderer" which is why I was so confused when what was happening was happening. It's the reason I made a post. 

Removing the "(max-width: #px)" is what made things work in this instance though. thanks

Comment: For the renderer you should setPixelRatio, but that is not implemented with a CSS media query. The vanilla JavaScript used is window.devicePixelRatio, but react-three-fiber has a more robust option. Adding a breakpoint in pixelRatio is (as for CSS layout elements) allows you to reduce resolution, balancing quality versus performance. 

For example, a mobile phone may have 2x dpi, but it is smaller and less powerful (than 4k desktop). It seems counterintuitive to reduce resolution, but you may not get 60fps otherwise. It's an inexact science. With a busy scene and layout shifts you will know.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
what is a "react-three-fiber"? I can't understand that.

Comment: It is a framework wrapper which manages state. It attempts to expedite or automate routine three.js code. There are modules available for common utility functions. However, it requires a deviation in code style. Like Angular.js or TypeScript, it boosts developers productivity.